# Difference between servletcontainer.init(webconfig) vs servletcontainer.init() vs servletcontainer.init(filterconfig)

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, servlet-container

Want to know the Difference between servletcontainer.init(webconfig) vs servletcontainer.init() vs servletcontainer.init(filterconfig) in prespective of pax web whiteboard in karaf OSGI

pls someone explain this.

Answer (score 1):

`servletcontainer` may mean anything in your question.

Servlet API specification defines these `init()` methods:

- `javax.servlet.Servlet#init(javax.servlet.ServletConfig config)`
- `javax.servlet.GenericServlet#init()` (no arguments)
- `javax.servlet.Filter#init(javax.servlet.FilterConfig config)`

So you should look for explanation directly in [Servlet specification](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=369). (Mind that I link to `javax` version of the specification. Currently the specification moved to [Jakarta Servlet](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/)).

Pax Web is an implementation of web-related specifications from OSGi CMPN R8 and the above methods are simply handled according to both Servlet API and OSGi CMPN (in that order).

Answer (score 0):

You can find more info and the way to configure the web container in the [Apache Karaf Container 4.x - Documentation](https://dlcdn.apache.org/karaf/documentation/4_x.html#_webcontainer_jsp_servlet) and also see this example: [Apache Karaf Servlet examples](https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/main/examples/karaf-servlet-example/README.md)